# Subversion, checkout and restrictions issue

Tags: svn

If I have a repo, say `repo1` with 100 folders in it and I want the user who is checking that out to only have access to say two of the folders, `dir1` and `dir2`.

How can this be done using where I just checkout the `repo1` folder. `svn co svn://repo1 dest`

I cant seem to find an efficient way of restricting access to the other 98 folders without individually writing a restriction line in my `authz` file.

If I have

```
[/]
user = 

[/repo1/dir1]
user = rw

[/repo1/dir2]
user = rw
```

I cannot then checkout the `repo1` folder as I do not have access to it.  But to have access to it, all folders will inherit access.

ANy help would be appreciated!!

Comment: FYI You used wrong syntax for path: repository-part must be defined differently `[repo1:/dir1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
[groups]
dev = Fred, Bill, Sue

[/]
* = r
@dev = rw

[/repo1/]
user = r

[/repo1/dir2]
user = rw

[/repo1/dir12]
user = rw

[/repo1/dir72]
user = rw
```

This says that everybody has read access by default, dev group has read-write everywhere and 'user' has rw only in three specific paths.

Note that permissions apply downwards and by default nobody has any permissions anywhere.  More information can be found [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

In general the strategy is to:

- Set the default for the whole repository to what most users should have.
- Structure your repository to reflect the project groupings logically this will usually also group the user permissions logically.
- Consider groupings of users & roles.
- Bear in mind that permissions percolate downwards

So instead of:

```
top-level-
  - Hundreds of directories
```

with hundreds of user permissions try to structure things more like:

```
top-level
  - Common Utilities
     - Command Line Utilities
     - GUI Utilities
     - Web Utilities
  - Database Stuff
  - Hardware Projects
     - HW_1
     - HW_2
  - Customer Projects
     - Retail Customers
        - Customer A
        - Customer B
     - Wholesale Customers
etc.
```

Then you can have a group of users that are maintainers for All Utilities, another for All  Customers, One for Databases, etc., (bearing in mind that one user can be a member of more than one group.  These will get the permissions set, as a group, for everything in the area and by default below, (nested within), it and you will only need to set permissions on individual groups that are special, i.e. **must** only be worked on by specific people.

Also keep in mind that SVN is a **version control system** as long as you are not giving admin rights away you can always undo, revert, bad changes.  If you have people that are so untrustworthy that you must not let them into anything because they will do too much damage the correct answer is to train them, move them to a role where they cannot do any damage or fire them.

Comment: The problem is, the other "98" folders then all have read access, when I want them to have no access.
This is a possible solution but most defintely a last resort

Comment: @AllanMacmillan - you **must** to write disable access rules explicitly for each nested into repo folder

Comment: @LazyBadger, so i must have a huge list of `[/repo1/dirX] user =` ?

Comment: @AllanMacmillan - yes :-(

Comment: Your answer is as correct as it can be.  I am working with the filesystem that generates our company website and therefore shifting the directories is not possible.  We have soo many subdirs already that 100 is actually quite small.  We need access to a parent folder with the stylesheets and scripts so all other folders have access to it too.  Thanks anyway